# How can I store the FULL directory of a FileChooser

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a program that stores the path of the folder you chose. The problem is that when I try to store the path to a String, it does not store the FULL directory.

If I select "C:\Users\n\Documents\English", it would store "C:\Users\n\Documents\"

How can I store the COMPLETE directory?

```
int result  = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);
    if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        path = fileChooser.getCurrentDirectory().toString().replace('\\', '/') + "/";
        textArea.append(path);
    }
```

Comment: Don't you just want `fileChooser.getSelectedFile()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is

```
fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath()
```

Comment: You can also use `File#getParent` if you just want the path without the file name...

Answer (score 1):

Try  `path = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getParent() + fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getName();`

This will append the file name to the directory string.

Comment: Use `getSelectedFile` which returns a `File`, which then you can use `getParent` and `getName` without messing with `getCurrentDirectory`...

Comment: `String path = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getPath()`...if you need to use, you can use `getAbsolutePath` or `getCanonicalPath` instead of `getPath`, that will return variations of the path depending on the information available to the `File` object and depending on what the OP is trying to achieve ;)